# In Sonar 3.4.1, why would the Projects widget show the same Rules Compliance (RCI) for two projects?

Tags: sonarqube

I have a sonar dashboard with two projects defined: Search and ProductService.  This dashboard has the "Projects" widget, that displays these columns:

[image: Projects widget showing duplicate RCI values]

Why would the Rules Compliance value be the same for these two projects, when displayed in this widget?

=======================================

This is a peculiar coincidence, an 'accident' perhaps.  Freddy suggested adding the 'Weighted Violations' column to the widget, and this revealed the coincidence.  The actual RCI values are 71.6628 % and 71.7208 %, which when rounded become 71.7% and 71.7%, a peculiar coincidence.  THIS is not a bug, but a coincidence.

[image: Projects widget showing duplicate RCI values, plus Weighted Violations]

Comment: Why couldn't they have the same value for this RCI metric? You get different values on their respective dashboard?

Comment: These projects appear together on the same dashboard -- shouldn't they have an individual (unique) RCI metric per project?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean. Each project has its own dashboard. Are you talking about a global dashboard? Could you please add a screenshot or move to the Sonar user mailing-list to discuss this matter?

Comment: Thanks David, I added a screenshot ...

Comment: In fact the question should have been "Why do I get exactly the same RCI for two different projects ? Potential bug ?"

Comment: To be sure that this is a bug and not just an accident, could you click on the 'Projects' link and add the column 'Weighted violations' to the 'Projects' Measure filter. Indeed RCI = 100 - (weighted_violations / (Lines of code * 100) )

Comment: Freddy, this is an "accident" and therefore is not a bug.  I added the 'Weighted violations' column, and manually did the Weighted-violations calculation for these two projects.  The numbers that I manually calculated were 3940 and 1645.  Using these weighted violations, the RCI percentages (rounded to four places rather than one) were 71.6628 % and 71.7208 %, respectively.  I have included a second screenshot above, with an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This an "accident" and therefore is not a bug. I added the 'Weighted violations' column, and manually did the Weighted-violations calculation for these two projects. The numbers that I manually calculated were 3940 and 1645. Using these weighted violations, the RCI percentages (rounded to four places rather than one) were 71.6628 % and 71.7208 %, respectively.